# Combining Jekyll post data with data from YAML to make a new blog feed

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, indieweb

I think I'm not even sure what I should be searching for. On my [Jekyll Blog](https://jacobrcampbell.com/blog/) I currently have just blog posts that have been written and listed with their full content on the main page and using pagination. I want to follow more Indie Web standards and follow a [PESOS](https://indieweb.org/PESOS) (Publish Elsewhere, Syndicate (to your) Own Site) method. I've figured out a way to get data from my Twitter (e.g. post_date, embed code, etc) into a YAML data file automatically. What I want to do is take the data from my posts and combine the data from Twitter and include those posts as if they were also blog posts (the plan is to do the same with Instagram as well).

I've tried a lot of things, but I'm not even sure what is the best way to go about doing this. I'm assuming that it will use something similar to [Using Jekyll, how do you alter an array's contents using a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56211971/using-jekyll-how-do-you-alter-an-arrays-contents-using-a-for-loop?newreg=d45a82d837c9469793c0cd810e3b2535), but I can't seem to make it work. My code for the blog posts is as follows currently:

```
{% for post in paginator.posts %}

{% if post.header.teaser %}
  {% capture teaser %}{{ post.header.teaser }}{% endcapture %}
{% else %}
  {% assign teaser = site.teaser %}
{% endif %}

{% if post.id %}
  {% assign title = post.title | markdownify | remove: "<p>" | remove: "</p>" %}
{% else %}
  {% assign title = post.title %}
{% endif %}

<div class="list__item">
  <article class="archive__item" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/CreativeWork">
    <h1 class="archive__item-title" itemprop="headline">
      {% if post.link %}
        <a href="{{ post.link }}">{{ title }}</a> <a href="{{ post.url | relative_url }}" rel="permalink"><i class="fas fa-link" aria-hidden="true" title="permalink"></i><span class="sr-only">Permalink</span></a>
      {% else %}
        <a href="{{ post.url | relative_url }}" rel="permalink">{{ title }}</a>
      {% endif %}
    </h1>

<p>Posted on <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.date | date: "%A %B %-d, %Y" }}</a> by <a href="/contact/">Jacob Campbell</a>.</p>

{{ post.content }}

  </article>
</div>
{% endfor %}

{% include paginator.html %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, if your `posts` and `tweets` do have the same structure in terms of fields you could [`concat`](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/concat/) the two:

```html
{% comment %} Given that you make the tweets accessible from site, as a collection, for example {% endcomment %}
{% assign posts = paginator.posts | concat: site.tweets | sort: "date" %} 
{% for post in posts %}
  <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
  <div>{{ post.content }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

***Mind that***, here I am also resorting the list after the `concat`, via the [`sort`](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/sort/) filter, so the tweets do appear in the normal time series of the posts.

And if your structures are not the same, you can always resort to the [`collection`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#page-variables) in which your `post` is:

```html
{% assign posts = paginator.posts | concat: site.tweets | concat: site.instagram | sort: "date" %} 
{% for post in posts %}
  {% if post.collection == 'posts' %}
    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
    <div>{{ post.content }}</div>
  {% elsif post.collection == 'tweets' %}
    {% comment %} If I am not mistaken, twitter have no title concept {% endcomment %}
    <h2>There was a bird singing about:</h2> 
    <div>{{ post.content }}</div>
  {% elsif post.collection == 'instagram' %}
    {% comment %} So, now, it can fit any social media of your choice {% endcomment %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```